# typescript: angle brackets and interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzGxRX?editors=0011
and I want to know the difference between `let square = <Square>{};` and  `let s: Square = { sideLength: 23, color: 'red'};`
Couldnt we have avoided the former and done the latter instead?

```
interface Shape {
    color: string
}

interface Square extends Shape {
    sideLength: number;
}

let square = <Square>{};
square.color = "blue";
square.sideLength = 10;
console.log(square);

let s: Square = { sideLength: 23, color: 'red'};
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Couldnt we have avoided the former and done the latter instead?

Absolutely. In TypeScript, initializers are not a coding preference, they're a way to ensure that your object fulfills the specification defined by the interface. Crucially, if you add a new non-optional property to your square, the `let s: Square = {...` variant will [blow up as expected](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Square%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sideLength%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09newProperty%3A%20number%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--------%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20square%20%3D%20%3CSquare%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Asquare.color%20%3D%20%22blue%22%3B%0D%0Asquare.sideLength%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20s%3A%20Square%20%3D%20%7B%20sideLength%3A%2023%2C%20color%3A%20'red'%7D%3B), while the other variant (cast and assign) will be silent. (And of course, someone might accidentally remove or forget to add one of the property assignments, which would again introduce an error of the sort that TypeScript is designed to avoid.)

Avoid casting whenever possible. Assuming your dependencies aren't circular (seldom the case), you can always re-write code like this to use initializers. If you want to create an object where some properties may be missing, define those properties as optional in the interface by adding a `?`:

```
interface Triangle {
    nonOptional: number;
    optional?: number;
}
const t: Triangle = {nonOptional: 1}; // no error
```

Answer (score 0):

They may seem like they function similarly, but they operate differently, and generate slightly different JavaScript output.

The first form allows you to create an empty object, while still maintaining the reference to the interface.  Attempting to add a property which doesn't exist on the interface will flag the property.  However, using the object without a property defined will not cause an error.

The code generated by the first form looks like:

```
var square = {};
square.color = "blue";
square.sideLength = 10;
console.log(square);
```

The second form creates the object inline, and will not allow you to create the object without providing all properties defined on the interface.  It's generated code looks like:

```
var s = { sideLength: 23, color: 'red' };
console.log(s);
```

In many cases, the second form would be preferred, but if you need to create an object before you have the values to fill all the properties, or if you want to create an object where some properties may be missing, the first form is necessary.

Try it for yourself: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Shape%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Square%20extends%20Shape%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sideLength%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20square%20%3D%20%3CSquare%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Asquare.color%20%3D%20%22blue%22%3B%0D%0Asquare.sideLength%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(square)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20s%3A%20Square%20%3D%20%7B%20sideLength%3A%2023%2C%20color%3A%20'red'%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(s)%3B)